# BufferedWriter problem

Tags: java, primes

I made a program which can generate primes. I want the program to write to file. When I generate primes up to Integer.Max_Value it doesn't write all of the primes for some reason and it just stops. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Primes {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    generate(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

}

// generate primes.
public static void generate(int limit) throws IOException {
     BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Primes.txt"));
     writer.write(2);
     for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            writer.write(Integer.toString(i));
            writer.newLine();
        }
    }
    writer.close();
}

// checking for primes
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= (Math.sqrt(n)); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: There is no such constant `Integer.Max_Value` Can you post your actual working code?

Comment: @Peter there is a constant..http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE

Comment: The first thing I noted is that you condition `i <= limit` is always true as the limit is the largest possible `int` value. ;)

Comment: @user681159, and you also know the compiler is case sensitive, so `MAX_VALUE` and `Max_Value` are not the same thing. ;)

Comment: I have changed my code from Integer.Max_Value to Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: At what point does it 'stop'?  Integer.MAX_VALUE is a large number (2^31-1) so your algorithm could just be taking a long time as the numbers get large.

Comment: @Jim, It should never stop because `i` is an `int` which can never be larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` by definition.

Comment: @Peter: The OP said it 'stops' (which is why I put the quotes around 'stops').

Comment: @Jim, Strangely it does 'stop' though it shouldn't.

Comment: @Peter: define "stop", which is the main problem with this whole thread -- the program stops producing output but continues running, or the program exits?

Comment: @Jim, All the above would be possible if you didn't have the code in front of you. ;) As you can see from the code, when the loop stops, the output stops, the thread stops, the program stops. There is no need to clarify this as they all co-inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your program isn't hanging at all, it's just taking a long time to do its work.

As the numbers get larger, the amount of time taken to check them increases in proportion to their square root.  Additionally, the distances between prime numbers is greater, the larger the numbers.  Putting these together, the speed at which primes are found will tail off quite quickly.

Have you attached a debugger to your program, and paused execution to inspect the local variables and see where it's got to?  Have you even put in `System.out.println("About to calculate for " + i);`?  How do your know your program "just stops"?

The first step should be some investigation into what your program's actually doing.  If you output timestamps with the println messages, you can also get an idea of how the speed of checking each individual number decays, and thus when you spot a pause you can have a rough estimate of how long the current check should take.

---

Besides, your program will never terminate, since you have an infinite outer loop.  Your `for` loop's terminating condition is `i <= Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which means it will run until it finds an `i` such that `i > Integer.MAX_VALUE`.  Can you name a value for `i` where that will hold true?

Answer (score 2):

I have logged to the bugs database and it has been accepted as a new bug which should appear in the [Bugs Database](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7049186) in a few day.

---

This looks to me like a bug in the JIT compiler.  It detects that i <= limit is always true (this doesn't happen for Integer.MAX_VALUE -1) and produces incorrect code.  If you run the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        generate(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        generate2(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("End of Main");
}

// generate primes.
public static void generate(int limit)  {
    int lastPrime = 0;
     for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2)
        if (isPrime(i))
            lastPrime = i;
    System.out.println("1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= "+lastPrime);
}

public static void generate2(int limit){
    int lastPrime = 0;
     for (int i = 3; i <= limit; i += 2)
        if (isPrime(i))
            lastPrime = i;
    System.out.println("2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= "+lastPrime);
}

// checking for primes
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

it prints

```
1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 39367
1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 55291
1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
1: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 49603
2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 2039
2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 2039
2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
2: Stopped generating at lastPrime= 3
End of Main
```